# Multiple form elements binding to one model attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I have a model

```
public class  Foo
{
  public string bar { get; set; }
  //Other stuff
}
```

In my view, I need to present the user with two radio buttons and a drop down list, with the drop down list acting as a third radio button in the group.

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.bar, "A") %>
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.bar, "B") %>
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.bar, ViewData["OtherUncommonOptions"] as SelectList)%>
```

What is the best approach to this problem?

For the view, I'm pretty confident that jQuery can make sure only one value is selected for `bar`. However if it's possible to avoid this that would be even better.

On the controller side, I'm a bit lost on how I'd go about binding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["OtherUncommonOptions"] = new SelectList(
            Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Value = x.ToString(), 
                Text = "item " + x 
            }),
            "Value",
            "Text"
        );
        return View(new Foo());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Foo model)
    {
        // model.Bar will contain the selected value here
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Bar, "A", new { id = "barA" }) %>
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Bar, "B", new { id = "barB" }) %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.Bar,
        ViewData["OtherUncommonOptions"] as SelectList,
        "-- value --",
        new { id = "barDDL" }
    ) %>

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

And the last part would be to ensure using javascript that if one of the two radio buttons is selected the drop down list clears its value and if a value is selected in the drop down list the radio buttons are deselected.

```
$(function() {
    $('#barA, #barB').click(function () {
        $('#barDDL').val('');
    });

    $('#barDDL').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#barA, #barB').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
});
```